# IE Automation Issue

Tags: vba, excel, ie-automation

I have a code to navigate to a website and fill up a form with 33 inputs.

This is the code:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://mylink.com"

Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For i = 0 To objCollection.Length
objCollection(i).innertext = "Test " & i
Next i

Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing
```

Now, this works like a charm. Not a single error.

> The input 1 receives "Test 1"; The input 2 receives "Test 2"; ... ;
>   The input 33 receives "Test 33";

But, the actual data that i need to pass is in my worksheet in the range AI43:AI75

If i change this part

```
 For i = 0 To objCollection.Length
objCollection(i).innertext = "Test " & i
Next i
```

To this

```
j = 1
For i = 0 To objCollection.Length
objCollection(i).innertext = Range("AI" & 42 + j).Text
j = j + 1
Next i
```

The output, each time is different, and always wrong. The order of the inputs go crazy and some inputs stay blank.

> Example: input 1 receives "data 1", input 2 receives "data 2", input 3
>   receives "data 30", input 4 receives nothing, input 5 receives "data
>   10".

And eachtime i run it, the output is different. Any ideas why? Can't figure it out.

Comment: why use `j` at all? why not just `43 + i`?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman You didn't know the more mathematical equations your processor has to complete the more efficient it is?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs - I think I slept through that lecture.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs same output. nothing changed

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs sorry, i wrote it wrong. i did j = j + 1

Comment: That wasn't me who provided you with a suggestion... But I will give you a possible solution in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using your `For i = ...` statement, see if a `For Each` statement would do what you need by iterating through the collection itself.

```
Dim IE As Object, i as Long
Dim objCollection As Object, o As Object  '  <--- New declaration

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://mylink.com"

Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each o In objCollection
    i = i + 1
    o.innerText = "Test " & i
Next o

Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing
```

Comment: @RyanWildry Updated answer

Comment: @K.Davis it didn't work. I think the problem is in the lenght of my cells. My range have cells with 200+ caracters. When i changed the cells to 10 caracters at most, it worked just fine.

Can't figure it out why. I'm running out of options

Comment: @K.Davis Thankkk you so much!!! It did work. I was trying with a different code. 

Using "For Each o" instead of "For i = 0 To objCollection.Lenght" doesn't let the program get lost. Dunno why, but it worked. I'll update the post with the answer

Comment: @Guilherme There's no need to update your question with the answer. Simply mark this one as accepted.